# ZF2 How to put adapter into registry

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I an using zend classes in my application (without the mvc). I would like to put my adapter instance into a container and use it in my other classes. This is what i have now.

**load.php**

```
$adapter = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter(array(
            'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
            'database' => DB_PREFIX.DB_NAME,
            'username' => DB_USER,
            'password' => DB_PW
    ));
```

How do i access $adapter in my other class?

**OtherClass.php**

```
 public class OtherClass{

     function __construct() {       
        //$adapter is needed here
        $this->_model = get_class($this);
        $this->sql = new Sql\Sql($this->dbo);
    }
}
```

Previously in ZF1 there is a Zend::Registry where i can set my variable. Then later access it again by calling the get method. However, i can't find similar cases in ZF2. I tried using ServiceManager but it seems not to be working in my scenario.

Appreciate any expert advices.

Answer (score 0):

ZF2 does not have a `Registry` like ZF1 does. Instead we have what's called a `ServiceManager`. You should use this SM to inject your dependencies into your Services.

You can read more information on the SM here -> http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.service-manager.intro.html

I'd recommend checking out ZfcUser on github -> https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser and checkout their Module.php file. It may help you get a better understanding of how a working example uses the SM to handle injection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does ServiceManager works for custom framework? I am not using Zend Framework 2

Comment: You can use it as standalone, too, yes. To find out how that's done, the best way currently - i guess - is to check out the UnitTests of the ServiceManager ;)